# How to convert multiple newlines to HTML tags except when in code?

Tags: php, html, search, replace

I've created a simple markdown editor for a blog site I'm making, but I'm having trouble in PHP converting newlines to HTML tags in some (not all) cases.
For example, I may have an article structured like the following:

```
A paragraph of text here.

Another paragraph of text here.

[code]Code here.

  More code.

  More code.

    More code.

  More code.

More code.[/code]

One more paragraph of text here.
```

For this kind of article, whenever there are two or more newlines characters in a row, I want to convert them to `</p><p>` HTML markup except when the newlines are within the `[code][/code]` tags.
As such, I can't do a simple search and replace of all instances of multiple newlines in a row or else it will convert the newlines within the `[code][/code]` tags as well.

What's the best way to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:markdown], and why do you say that you're creating "a simple markdown editor"? Your syntax isn't even close to [Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Comment: My example was greatly simplified for the sake of argument. All I'm really asking about is how to convert newlines in some cases but not others. I will remove the markdown tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: Looks more like BBCode, it's often easier to control spacing using css as opposed to actually converting it, for example `white-space: pre`;

Comment: I don't understand how this solves my problem. For example, if I do `str_replace("\r\n\r\n", '</p><p>', $article)`, then I will get a bunch of `</p><p>` HTML within my `[code][/code]` tags, which I don't want.